# Ansible Playbook- Parallel Execution

Tags: ansible

I have 3 tasks in a playbook. My requirement is to complete the first task and then the second and third tasks should happen in parallel. As by default, these three tasks will happen one after the other, is there a way to make the second and third task in parallel once the first one is done?

```
- hosts: conv4
  remote_user: username

  tasks:
  - name: Start Services
    script: app-stop.sh
    register: console

- hosts: patchapp

  remote_user: username
  become_user: username
  become_method: su

  tasks:
  - name: Stop APP Services
    script: stopapp.sh
    register: console

  - debug: var=console.stdout_lines

- hosts: patchdb

  remote_user: username
  become_user: username
  become_method: su

  tasks:
  - name: Stop DB Services
    script: stopdb.sh
    register: console

  - debug: var=console.stdout_lines
```

I need to run Start Services task first and then once it is complete i need to run Stop APP Services and Stop DB Services tasks parallely.

Comment: Hi, i need to implement the tasks on different hosts. Can you please let know how we can do it.

Comment: Well, by defaut a playbook is played on several hosts in parallel so I don't understand what the problem is. Edit your question and ask it better by explaining the situation and the problem

Comment: Maybe you can add an example of your Playbook, and what you expect Ansible to do.

Comment: Hi.. ok let me put it in a better way. i have three tasks. 1st task i need to do it on host 1. once this task completes, i need to do 2nd task(on host 2) and 3rd task(on host 3) in parallel. Please let me know if this is not clear.

Comment: I have edited the question and posted a sample playbook. Please take a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

**1.Import playbook** works fine.

**play.yml**

```
- import_playbook: play1.yml
- import_playbook: play2.yml
```

**play1.yml**

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: 'play1: {{ ansible_host }}'
```

**play2.yml**

```
- hosts:
    - vm2
    - vm3
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: 'play2: {{ ansible_host }}'
```

**2.Loop over include_tasks and delegate_to** is a nogo.

An option would be to loop over include_tasks and delegate_to inside the task (see below). But there is an unsolved bug [delegate_to with remote_user on ansible 2.0](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/13323) .

[Workflows](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/workflows.html) in Ansible Tower require license.

> Workflows are only available to those with Enterprise-level licenses.

**play.yml**

```
- name: 'Test loop delegate_to'                                                              
  hosts: localhost                                                                           
  gather_facts: no                                                                           
  vars:                                                                                      
    my_servers:                                                                              
      - vm2                                                                                  
      - vm3                                                                                  
  tasks:                                                                                     
    - name: "task 1"                                                                         
      debug:                                                                                 
        msg: 'Task1: Running at {{ ansible_host }}'                                          
    - include_tasks: task2.yml                                                               
      loop: "{{ my_servers }}"
```

**task2.yml**

```
- debug:
    msg: 'Task2: Running at {{ ansible_host }}'
  delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
```

**ansible-playbook play.yml**

```
PLAY [Test loop delegate_to]         
TASK [task 1] 
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: 'Task1: Running at 127.0.0.1'
TASK [include_tasks] 
included: ansible-examples/examples/example-014/task2.yml for localhost
included: ansible-examples/examples/example-014/task2.yml for localhost
TASK [debug] 
ok: [localhost -> vm2] => 
  msg: 'Task2: Running at vm2'
TASK [debug] 
ok: [localhost -> vm3] => 
  msg: 'Task2: Running at vm3'
PLAY RECAP
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```